# Kotlin from Java: is a field nullable or not?

Tags: java, kotlin

When accessing Kotlin classes from Java, is it possible during runtime to tell if a particular field is nullable or not? Also, is it possible to tell if a class is a data class?

Even a guess would be sufficient for my purposes. Using reflection is also fine.

Comment: Do you want to programmatically or just visually?

Comment: @nhaarman programmatically

Comment: You probably can use [`KType.isMarkedNullable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/index.html). But I don't know how can you get a type of variable in Kotlin.

Comment: @nhaarman omg I know you, you are the mockito-kotlin guy! Great job working on that library btw!

Comment: Re data class: [since Kotlin 1.1](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/src/kotlin/reflect/KClass.kt#L117), you can just do `MyClass::class.isData`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have a `java.lang.reflect.Field` instance for a property, you can first obtain the original Kotlin representation of the property by converting it to the `kotlin.reflect.KProperty` instance with `kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping`, and then get the type and check its nullability or anything else:

```
public static boolean isNullable(Field field) {
    KProperty<?> property = ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinProperty(field);
    return property.getType().isMarkedNullable();
}
```