# NfcAdapter is not nullable, but is being provided by @Provides @Singleton @javax.annotation.Nullable android.nfc.NfcAdapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations, dagger

I have problem with returning nullable NfcAdapter through my Dagger module. Here it is:

```
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @Nullable
  public NfcAdapter provideNfcAdapter() {
    return NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context);
  }
```

However the project can't be build and i receive error message:

> error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.nfc.NfcAdapter is not nullable, but is being provided by @Provides @Singleton @javax.annotation.Nullable android.nfc.NfcAdapter

How it can be resolved? I have similiar provide method for my BluetoothAdapter and it works as expected.

I try to initialize it as below in my Activity:

```
var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null @Inject set
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add a `@Nullable` annotation to the field. Any annotation that has the simple name "Nullable" will do, as listed in [the docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Provides.html) and [the code](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/dagger-2.17/java/dagger/model/DependencyRequest.java#L51-L60).

Though you can mark the nullability in Kotlin using `?`, this does not publish the "nullable" information from Kotlin to Java: a Java processor like Dagger cannot read the class file to determine that the field is meant to be nullable. (This is [possible through some Kotlin reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41097546/1426891), but Dagger does not do it as of v2.17.) Though your code is safe, Dagger cannot determine that by reading the bytecode, and it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

**Brief Answer**

--> Delete `@Nullable` line

It happens because you put the `@Nullable` annotation in a method that can not return null.  Android Studio is telling you that `NfcAdapter` can not be null. Deleting the `@Nullable` annotation should work.

**Deep explanation**

In my case, I had this method in my dagger 2 module.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Nullable
AuthenticationInterceptor provideInterceptor(@Nullable String authToken) {
    if (authToken != null) {
        return new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I found out that my class AuthenticationInterceptor which implements Interceptor

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {
}
```

couldn't return null (and I was returning null from it in case there was no authToken), then AS gave me the following error.

```
AuthenticationInterceptor is not nullable, but is being provided by @Provides @Singleton ...
```

Not returning null from my method resolved the issue. (Removing the @Nullable annotation and excluding the return null).

```
@Provides
@Singleton
AuthenticationInterceptor provideInterceptor(@Nullable String authToken) {
    return new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);
}
```

**Conclusion**

I did that because I was already handling these nullable things in the activities. In case the user has no authorization token, I didn't even try to make the retrofit call. I just asked him to sign in.

Comment: This is a correct solution for you, because `provideInterceptor` cannot return `null`, but [`NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(Context)` is allowed to return `null`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#getDefaultAdapter(android.content.Context)). Therefore, deleting `@Nullable` is a bad idea.